# Window Will not Respond to Messages

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

As usual I'm experiencing a very strange problem.

In fact, I'm not so sure what the problem actually is, but I am sure what the symptoms are.
The application is receiving messages, handling the messages, and calling APIs, but to no avail, except in some exceptional-seeming circumstances.

I'm trying to catch a keypress, the escape key. When the application receives it, it calls `PostQuitMessage()` and finishes processing (cleanup) later.
The problem is that when `PostQuitMessage()` is called, *nothing happens.*
The window is still sitting there, and I assume the API fails (but it returns void, so I can't tell) because I see nothing on Spy++ that refers to `WM_QUIT`, `WM_CLOSE` or the like.

The things that result in the window's closure include clicking the close button [x] or dragging the window from the non-client area or title bar, and than pressing escape. Simply clicking the window, "alt-tabbing?" to the window, and everything I else can think of does not allow the window to respond, although the messages are being processed.

I'll post relevant code below. If anyone has any requests, suggestions, or solutions, they are welcome! Thank you for your time and have a good day.

This is the window procedure; it's address is stored in `GWLP_USERDATA` in a similar manner to the method described in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article. I've used this before in other apps and have never encountered this problem, The handle received is valid -- the function just doesn't work!?

```
LONG_PTR MainWindow::HandleMessage(UINT Message,
    WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam) {
        switch(CurrentState) {
        case Introduction:
            return HandleIntroMessage(Message, WParam, LParam);
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(Window(), Message, WParam, LParam);
        }
}

LONG_PTR MainWindow::HandleIntroMessage(UINT Message,
    WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam) {
        switch(Message) {
            case WM_KEYDOWN:
                switch (WParam) {
                    case VK_ESCAPE:
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        return false;
                }
            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(Window(), Message, WParam, LParam);
        }
}
```

And part of the body of `wWinMain()`.

```
std::unique_ptr<ApplicationMutex> EnsureOneInstance(new ApplicationMutex);


    /*
    * If the instance is not first, return with the return value of the API
    * SetForegroundWindow after trying to find the window. 
    */
    if(!EnsureOneInstance->IsInstanceFirst(L"SDV") ) {
        (SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(nullptr, L"SDV") ) );
        return 1;
    }

    /*
    * Create and show our main window; initialize the frame.
    */
    std::unique_ptr<MainWindow> MainWin(new MainWindow() );
    MainWin->SwitchState(Introduction);
    MainWin->CreateWindowWithUserFormat();


    ShowWindow(MainWin->Window(), SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    SetActiveWindow(MainWin->Window() );
    SetFocus(MainWin->Window() );

    assert(MainWin->Window() != nullptr);

    std::unique_ptr<ApplicationEngine> SDV(new ApplicationEngine(MainWin->Window(),
        ThisInstance, CmdLine, CmdShow) );
    SDV->Initialize();

    MSG Message;
    int Res = 1;

    while(Res = GetMessage(&Message, MainWin->Window(), 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Message);
        DispatchMessage(&Message);
    }

    if(Res == -1) {
        return GetLastError();
    }
```

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: As I've said, I'm not too sure _what is relevant code here_, if anyone needs more code I will be happy to post.

Comment: What are you doing with that mutex?

Comment: It's an abstraction of a named mutex; it ensures that there's only one instance of the application running. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I see a couple of errors, but none explains your behavior, maybe there are more in the hidden code: 1) You forgot the `break` sentences in your switches, so you are actually posting the quit message on any key down. 2) the condition in the `while` misses some parenthesis: it should be `((Res = GetMessage(...)) > 0)`.

Comment: Doesn't a return render a break statement useless?

Comment: @MaxBozzi: Yes, but two of your `case` statements do not end with a return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `GetMessage` call you're only processing messages for `MainWin->Window()`, but `PostQuitMessage` posts a thread message that isn't bound to any particular window. Therefore your `GetMessage` will never retrieve it. You should pass NULL for the second parameter instead of the window handle.

(Additionally, you have a logic error because of operator precedence - `Res` will only ever be 1 or 0, not -1, although this isn't responsible for your problem).

Comment: Thanks! It works. You lifesaver, you! But that doesn't explain why dragging the window causes this behavior (or I don't see it). What I mean is, I can see why the `[x]` is bound to the window, but I don't understand why this occurs only if you don't click + drag the window.

Comment: Reading that comment again I'm still not being clear. Let me quote my post: "dragging the window from the non-client area or title bar, and than pressing escape [closes the window]", my question is _why?_

Comment: Do you mean pressing escape while dragging, or drag first and then press escape?

Comment: Only dragging first and than pressing escape. Sorry for the delay, BTW.

Comment: To be honest I don't know why that would be - seems very strange to me.

Comment: Hmm. I'll let you know if I find out why.